# Duplicate Title Tags.

Tags: seo

Google analytics is showing 29 duplicate title tags on my php. This is an ecommerce site and I know that duplicate title tags are annoying to the spiders that crawl a website.I would like to fix this and stream line the problem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO and belongs to [Webmasters.SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com).

Comment: these people had a similar problem http://forum.diversesolutions.com/archive/index.php/t-495.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate product title | category | ID (if you are product detail page) dynamically with tittleVariable with in the title tag to avoid duplicate.